# Parent div to change dimension when inner image rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have a modal containing one or more images and these images can rotate.

My issue is when image rotate it overflow the parent div. I wish to have the container to change dimension to always fit the image (images).

I created a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNENge)** to have a look.

I tried to change many and many **css** properties without success...

Jade:

```
.overlay
.fake-modal
  .content
    img.img(src='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-300-200-2.jpg')
    .wrapper
      button.left rotate left
      button.right rotate right
```

Less:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.fake-modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;

  .content {
    position: relative;

    .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

js:

```
var angle = 0;
var btnLeft = $('.left');
var btnRight = $('.right');

btnLeft.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  angle = angle - 90;
  rotate(angle);
});

btnRight.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  angle = angle + 90;
  rotate(angle);
});

function rotate(rotateDegrees) {
  var r = 'rotate(' + rotateDegrees + 'deg)';
  var img = $('.img');
  img.css({
    '-moz-transform': r,
    '-webkit-transform': r,
    '-o-transform': r,
    '-ms-transform': r
  });
}
```

Comment: You should try to use the image as background `cover`of the container and then rotate the background image. http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Comment: I just tried your solution and it has the same effect... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJLpoe?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `getBoundingClientRect()`

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNENge

Comment: That woks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you may set fixed width and height to div contaning image.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbQXJP

```
`.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.fake-modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;

  .content {
    position: relative;

    .imgContainer {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;

      .img {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
      }
    }

    .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: The images are dynamic and I don't know their dimensions.